# Android Studio - failed to connect to [ip address]: Network is unreachable

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, terminal, adb

I'm trying to connect to my physical Android device via tcpip the same way I always do; by calling

`adb connect xx.xx.xx.xxx:5555`

in Android Studio's terminal, but the command hangs for about 20 seconds then I get this error:

```
failed to connect to 'xx.xx.xx.xxx:5555': Network is unreachable
```

I've never seen this error before, what causes it? I've confirmed that my laptop and the device are on the same network, and i've confirmed that I get this error no matter which device I try to connect to (I have multiple).

The usual solution of calling adb kill-server followed by adb start-server hasn't remedied the issue, nor has any combination of invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio. My Android Studio version is 3.4.2.

What can I do to connect to fix this network is unreachable error?

Comment: Connect the device to your computer with USB and try again

Comment: try to ping your device from terminal

Comment: @Zain ping is timing out, must be a local network issue. Thanks

Comment: @Cody you could also check if you've a firewall or security settings that blocks your device .. welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes restarting your phone helps as well, or turn off wifi and enable it back

Answer (score 0):

Make sure android-studio and device are in same network.Otherwise it will not connect.

**E.g**

Your computer is connected with broadband and your device is connected with mobile data.Then it will not connect.

Comment: Yes, they're on the same network. I've successfully connected to this device thousands of times, it just stopped working randomly on Friday.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a problem with firewall. Please check whether you have allowed it in the firewall settings.

Eg. 
If it's in opensuse, you have to allow it through yast > Security and Users > Firewall > add the server to the specific zone on the configuration pane.

Let me know the OS you are using.